# bluetooth capabilities (via J2ME)

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth

I'm looking for some specific info about bluetooth capabilities (via J2ME):

1. is it possible to program externally with which 'name' given mobile will present itself to external bluetooth world ?
2. is it possible for two phone to 'speak' with each other in terms of sending info/data under (not manual) software control ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you mean "can you set the device's friendly name", no you can't.  You can access the device's friendly name, however this is only really for presenting to the user.  To address another device you would use its bluetooth address.
2. Yes you can use RFCOMM to create a connection between two devices and transfer bytes between them.

Comment: Well, I think I will argue some in this point:
in my (very old) mobile, SonyEricsson k800i, in bluetooth settings I have option of Phone name.
And its official description says: 
Enter a name  for your phone. The name is shown in other Bluetooth  devices when your phone is found.Actually this is exactly this what I need.
The question is, if it is doable from ouside, via J2ME programming.
As far as I know there is quite a separation between J2ME programming layer and physical layer of phone setting

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear that my answers were in the context of doing things programmatically in J2ME.  Of course you can set the phone's name manually from the settings menu.  There is no way to do this within a J2ME app.